# Asp.net GridView ignore the CellSpacing attribute

Tags: asp.net, xhtml, gridview

I am having some difficulties with a GridView here, a client asked me to put some space between the cells, typically I would do CellSpacing="5" however it seems it is not working, I tried a few stuff and everything is rewritten...

Code I tried :

```
<asp:GridView ID="gvShoppingCart" runat="server" CellSpacing="5" Width="100%" AutoGenerateColumns="false">

<some-formating-columns-here />

</asp:GridView>
```

What is actually rendered is :

```
<table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" summary="">
    <thead>
        <tr class="AspNet-GridView-Header">
            <th scope="col">Produit</th>
            <th scope="col"> </th>
            <th class="Center" scope="col">Quantité</th>
            <th class="Right" scope="col">  Prix Unitaire  </th>
            <th class="Right" scope="col">Prix</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
<body-columns-here />
</table>
```

I have no idea of what to add now...

Any suggestions ?

Comment: Could you confirm which version of the ASP.NET framework you're using, and what browser you're seeing this behaviour in? Also, have you got any control adaptors defined? (You should check the /App_Browsers folder for .browser files).

Answer (score 3):

I assume you are using a reset.css therefore you might need to consider doing the following;

in your css file;

```
table {border-collapse:separate; border-spacing:5px}
```

border-spacing is not cross browser so you may also need to add CellSpacing="5" on the GridView.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using CSS.  If you know the class that is being applied to the HTML element you could use CSS-padding for that particular CSS class.  I would give that a shot.

An example would be:

```
<asp:GridView ID="gvShoppingCart" runat="server" CssClass="gvShoppingFormat" Width="100%" AutoGenerateColumns="false">
<some-formating-columns-here />
</asp:GridView>
```

Your CSS class would look like:

```
.gvShoppingFormat td {
     padding-left: 5px;
     padding-right: 5px;
}
```

Comment: Padding isn't the right option since it will add space inside of the cell, not outside. I want to put really 5 pixels between each cell containers. I would be margin: 5px, but it seems it is not enough.